# How to access sub-chunks's data of .wav file?

Tags: c, file, struct, binary-data

How to access sub-chunks's data of **.wav** file?
I've been trying to copy binary data (first 44 bytes) to a struct variable (size of 44 bytes). But there is a problem: I'm convinced that I'd copied binary data from the file `input` to a struct named `hdr`.

But when I'm trying to display hdr.ChunkID which contains "RIFF" (array of char) it doesn'y print "RIFF".. It prints nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct FMT
{
    char        Subchunk1ID[4];
    int         Subchunk1Size;
    short int   AudioFormat;
    short int   NumChannels;
    int         SampleRate;
    int         ByteRate;
    short int   BlockAlign;
    short int   BitsPerSample;

} fmt;

typedef struct DATA
{
    char        Subchunk2ID[4];
    int         Subchunk2Size;
    int         Data[441000]; // 10 secs of garbage. he-he)
} data;

typedef struct header
{
    char        ChunkId[4];
    int         ChunkSize;
    char        Format[4];
    fmt         S1;
    data        S2;
} Header;



int main()
{
    FILE *input = fopen("in.wav", "rb");
    FILE *output = fopen("out.wav", "wb");

    unsigned char buf[64];
    Header hdr;

    if(input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open wave file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fread(&buf, sizeof(char), 64, input);
    fwrite(&buf, sizeof(char), 64, output);

    fread(&hdr, sizeof(char), 64, output);
    printf("\n>>> %s", hdr.ChunkId);         /* Here it is. */

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Cannot understand what is wrong.

Comment: If you need to read 44 bytes, why are you reading 64? What will you do with the extra 20 bytes you read?

Comment: I have a program which shows me the first 64 bytes and nterprets them... e.g. the first 4 bytes ---> "RIFF" and so on.

Comment: For the rest of the data, you might want to check (with e.g. `sizeof(Header)`) that the structures you have are not padded. If the value from `sizeof` differs from what it should be you need to tell the compiler that the structures should not be padded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you try to read from an write-only file handle. Read into `hdr` with the first `fread` call. No need for the `buf` array (or a second read):

```
Header hdr;

/* Opening files ... */

fread(&hdr, 1, 64, input);
fwrite(&hdr, 1, 64, output);

printf("\n>>> %4.4s", hdr.ChunkId); 

/* ... */
```

Also note that `hdr.ChunkID` will **not** be terminated as a string, so printing it as a string might print seemingly random characters after the header. This is why I added field length and precision in the `printf` call.

Comment: Add that he's reading/writing to the address of `buf` anyway, e.g. instead of `fread(&buf, sizeof(char), 64, input);` it should be `fread(buf, sizeof(char), 64, input);`. Also, there's no guarantee sizeof(Header) is equal to 64.

Comment: @someguy For an array, `array` and `&array` both returns a pointer to the first element in the array.

Comment: @someguy And `sizeof(hdr)` is _not_ 64 bytes, its well over 44000 bytes, so I've changed my code to only read/write 64 bytes. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Oops, didn't read the code properly, but my point is that because of alignment and that the length of `int` and `short int` is implementation-specific, there's no guarantee it'll work properly. (Though in this case, it will, because we're just reading to `char[4]` which is first in the struct.)

Comment: @someguy You're right that there's no guarantee, but I think it's pretty likely the structures will be properly padded (that is, not at all).